# Azure Function timer trigger not triggering when deployed

Tags: azure, azure-functions, timer-trigger

I have a timer-triggered function setup like this

```
public class PBARCronTrigger
{
    private readonly eReserveFunctions _settings;

    public PBARCronTrigger(IOptions<eReserveFunctions> settings)
    {
        _settings = settings.Value;
    }

    [FunctionName("PBARCronTrigger")]
    public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("%PBARCron%")] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"PBARCronTrigger function executing at: {DateTime.Now}");

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
```

and I have the app setting for PBARCron set to every 5 minutes:

[image]

but the trigger is not triggering. I connect to live logs and nothing happens. It keeps on saying "No new trace in the past x min(s)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cron expression doesn't look right to me. Checking it in an [evaluator](https://crontab.guru/#0_0/5_0_*_*_*) even states that it's non-standard and may not work in every environment.

I think what you want is `0-55/5 * * * *`, or more simply, `*/5 * * * *`.